# iOS:animating destination segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue

I'm looking how to animate the transition between master and destination segue but I have found any example (Objective-C). Any of you knows how can I animate the transition between segue?

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

you can use different types for the transition, with custom segues and unwind segues 
http://www.appcoda.com/custom-segue-animations/

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        thirdVCView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(thirdVCView.transform, 0.001, 0.001)
        thirdVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(thirdVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

        firstVCView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, 0.0, -screenHeight)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in

            self.sourceViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, you need to take a look in [UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollertransitioningdelegate).

Here goes some resource on it

1. [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html)
2. [Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions)
3. [Appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-view-controller-transitions-tutorial/)